# How to create parameterized event in NATIVESCRIPT?

Tags: xml, telerik, hybrid-mobile-app, nativescript

The problem i'm trying to solve is,  I want to have a tap event with a parameter in XML:

I know that, this format will not work. so what is the correct format?

Use case: in a list view you want to open a url

Cheers

Comment: Hi Kevin, welcome to SO. Have you tried anything yet? To get support here, you must show you tried something already, and your research effort. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't the params set in the XML directly consumable in the js?

Like on a regular tap

```
var button = args.object;
var param = button.myparam;
```

Where the XML would have been

```
<Button myparam="test"
```

I knew someone who used to pass data around in the XML over just using args.object.bindingContext and using the bound data directly.  I THINK this is how he was doing it.

So on a Listview itemTap event I think it'd be something like this

```
var param = args.view.myparam;
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm using a listview and passed an object array to the it in which has a URL property,  so I'm trying to have a `tap` or `listTap` event defined and pass the `{{ url }}` to it. something like this:  `label tap="ontap( {{  url }})" .  <- I know that this syntax is wrong, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of doing something like this would be to just have the onTap="myTapEvent" on the ListView itself.

Then in the js, you would get the index of the tapped item and fetch it from the original array:

```
exports.myTapEvent = function(args){
   var tappedItem = myListArray.getItem(args.index);
   var url = tappedItem.url;
}
```

I am not sure if it is possible to add events to specific items inside the ListView.itemTemplate...